# Endless loop during installation on openmeetings

Tags: openmeetings

I am installing OpenMeetings on RHEL 7.0. During installation i get a message with an endless loop saying:

```
 WARN 02-07 07:56:15.178 ConfigurationDao.java 117006 123 org.apache.openmeetings.db.dao.basic.ConfigurationDao [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] - Could not find key in configuration CONF_KEY: application.base.url
 WARN 02-07 07:56:15.179 ConfigurationDao.java 117007 123 org.apache.openmeetings.db.dao.basic.ConfigurationDao [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] - Could not find key in configuration CONF_KEY: number.minutes.reminder.send
```

Is there any solution to this?